# Illegal mix of collations - MariaDB 10.4 - LUA

Tags: mysql, lua, mariadb

[My lua codes for mysql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ioJo0.png)

[Getting these error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwztG.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as the error message says, `yellowpages_posts.realUser` uses collation utf8mb4_unicode_ci and `users.identifier` uses utf8mb_general_ci.

you have to explicitly set the collation of one to the other, e.g.

```sql
yellowpages_posts.realUser = users.identifier COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

also checkout https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html